# Simple TaxiMeter

Tags: java, android, calculator

I want to make a simple calculator. Customer will enter the how many kilometers he/she went and the calculator will give the total amount. The opening amount is 4 and the rate per km is 1.4.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        double km;
        int y;
        double x;
        x = 1.4;
        y = 4;

        TextView tabela = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tabela);
        EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        String written = number.getText().toString();
        km = Double.parseDouble(written);
        tabela.setText("Total Amount" + ((km*x)+y));
    }
}
```

Comment: And the error being?

Comment: It is not working. App keeps closing itself. So l thought there is something wrong in coding. But l couldn't receive a satisying answer yet. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number.getText().toString()` immediately returns an empty string.

You need a `Button` and a click listener.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tabela;
    EditText number;
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
            String written = number.getText().toString();
            km = Double.parseDouble(written);
            tabela.setText("Total Amount" + ((km*x)+y));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabela = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tabela);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

        b = ... // find button here
        b.setOnClickListener(this); // to the activity
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But the problem is not button, l can manage it through XML part. The problem is code is not working. App keeps closing. that's thy I asked if there is something wrong in coding.

Comment: Yes there is something wrong with your code. The edittext is empty... causing your app to close as soon as you open it, and you would see that if you **read the logcat**.... You **need** a button, or some other input to not get the text as soon as the Activity opens.